# django: why does an empty queryset trigger NoReverseMatch exception?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

My url pattern for models looks like this:

```
url(r'^models/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ThreediModelView.as_view(), 
    name='models'),
```

As long as a pass an existing pk to my `get_queryset()` method I get a valid response. Once an ID that does not exist is passed to the view, a

`NoReverseMatch at /models/models/9999/`

exception is thrown. I don't really understand why. Is not allowed to return an empty queryset? I do not check explicitly in my template if the object list is empty.

**view**

```
class ThreediModelView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    """
    Return a ThreediModel queryset, possibly filtered
    """

    model = ThreediModel
    template_name = 'models.html'
    context_object_name = 'threedi_models'
    search_fields = ["display_name", "slug", "status"]
    search_paceholder = SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER
    # default empty search
    search_str_raw = ""

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        :return: ThreediLog entries per revision. revision hash can
             be found in self.kwargs
        """
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')

        qs = ThreediModel.objects.filter(
            threedi_model_repository_id=pk)

        self.search_str_raw = (
            self.request.GET.get('search') or self.search_str_raw
        )

        self.search_paceholder = (
            self.search_str_raw if self.search_str_raw
            else SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER
        )

        if self.search_str_raw:
            entry_query = inpy_search.get_query(
            self.search_fields, self.search_str_raw
            )
            qs = qs.filter(entry_query)
            logger.info(
            "[+] Found {0:d} entries for search {1}".format(
                len(qs), self.search_str_raw)
            )

        return qs
```

**traceback**

```
NoReverseMatch at /models/models/9999/
Reverse for 'revisions' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'models\\/revisions/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9010/models/models/9999/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'revisions' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'models\\/revisions/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
Exception Location: /home/vagrant/.buildout/eggs/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 452
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
```

Comment: Please show the view and full traceback.

Comment: Is the url supposed to have "/models/models/"? Maybe you are generating the url incorrectly on the template. Look for the url template tag.

Comment: @Alasdair updated my question

Comment: There's clearly still lots of missing information here. For example, the error message is clearly telling us it can't find the `revisions` URL, and you haven't shown us where you are using that URL in your template or its definition in urls.py.

Comment: Absolutely right.  The problem properly is in the template. There are quite some url template tags.

Comment: Found the bug: ``<a href="{% url 'revisions' threedi_model.pk  %}">`` ``threedi_model`` did not exist of course. Thanks for thinking along guys.